# Ultraextend is slower than router

Tags: wireless-networking

I have an uktraXtend Wi-Fi extender and when a device is connected to it the download speeds are quite a bit slower than when connected to the router. This applies when I have the device next to the extender so it’s not because I’m close to the router. I’ve installed it correctly as best as I can tell. Is there something I should be doing or is the ultraXtend not a good Wi-Fi extender?

Answer (score 0):

UltraXtend is a scam. But keep reading!

Basic Wi-Fi repeaters suffer doubly from the half-duplex nature of Wi-Fi transmissions. Being connected to the repeater instead of the actual router/AP reduces achievable bandwidth to less than 50%. A single radio means the repeater can only talk to either its upstream network or its downstream devices, but never simultaneously. Radio interference is also a problem, because you'll end up with two networks on the same channel.

There's an easy way to solve this: just add one more radio to the repeater. So basically just throw money at the problem. Premium mesh systems go one step further and use a dedicated network for the mesh, so these units have three radios (2.4 GHz and 2x 5 GHz).

If you must use a repeater, it should have at least two radios. You also need a 5 GHz upstream network or you'll have very limited performance. High-spec repeaters are rather expensive.

So now you know about the intrinsic limitations of Wi-Fi repeaters. Why is UltraXtend a scam? It has only one radio. It only supports 802.11n (very outdated). It only supports 2.4 GHz. All this combined make it painfully slow.